# Python: How can I import waterways from OpenStreetMaps as a graph so I can do graph analysis with networkx

Tags: python, graph, networkx, overpass-api, osmnx

Thanks at first for actually taking the time to help me :-)
I want to create a undirected graph from waterways for example from the canals of Venice or Amsterdam.

OpenStreetMaps has such a graph of a waterway network of these cities, but the OSMnx package does not have such a filter to filter the waterways (or maybe I don't know it yet ;-) ).

```
import osmnx as ox

G = ox.graph_from_bbox(52.36309012572587,4.890326718121118,52.36590601699889,4.898316757037793, network_type='all')
G_projected = ox.project_graph(G)
ox.plot_graph(G_projected)
```

I thought I was possible to just download the whole map, and then filter on just the waterway network. But I don't know how to go further about this. OSMnx would be the best as I then immediately have a graph which I can use for functions of networksx such as Dijkstra's shortest path.

Another way I was thinking of was overpass package:

```
import overpass
import networkx as nx

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


api= overpass.API()
data = api.get('way(52.36309012572587,4.890326718121118,52.36590601699889,4.898316757037793);(._;>;)', verbosity='geom')
[f for f in data.features if f.geometry['type'] == "LineString"]
```

But this still doesn't work, because I haven't figured out how to filter the data and transform it to a graph for so that networkx can use it.

Hope you guys (and girls :-) ) can help me, because I have no clue how to go further.

Kind regards,

Jeroen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use OSMnx to get other types of infrastructure such as canals, railways, powerlines, etc, as described in [this example](https://github.com/gboeing/osmnx-examples/blob/v0.14.0/notebooks/08-custom-filters-infrastructure.ipynb), using the `custom_filter` parameter:

```py
import osmnx as ox
ox.config(use_cache=True, log_console=True)
G = ox.graph_from_place('Amsterdam', retain_all=False, truncate_by_edge=False,
                        simplify=True, custom_filter='["waterway"~"canal"]')
fig, ax = ox.plot_graph(G)
```

Comment: Thanks, if you type infrastructure='way["waterway"] it works, now I just need to set the graph right! :-)