# Plotting/importing rivers in OSMnx

Tags: openstreetmap, osmnx

I found someone asked a question for how to plot/import the objects other than roads, but he/she didn't get the answer.

Here is the link: [Plotting different area objects in OSMnx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53271216/plotting-different-area-objects-in-osmnx)

I was able to download/install OSMnx and run the examples of OSMnx at "https://github.com/gboeing/osmnx-examples.git".

My interest is on water (i.e., river, reservoir, lake, etc.).

How can I import and plot river/reservoir/lake of Open Street Map from Python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52411170/7321942), to model and plot waterways:

```py
import osmnx as ox
ox.config(use_cache=True, log_console=True)
G = ox.graph_from_place('Amsterdam', retain_all=False, truncate_by_edge=False,
                        simplify=True, custom_filter='["waterway"~"canal"]')
fig, ax = ox.plot_graph(G)
```

More details available in [this example](https://github.com/gboeing/osmnx-examples/blob/v0.14.0/notebooks/08-custom-filters-infrastructure.ipynb).

Comment: By the way, where can I get some information that I can substitute the argument of "infrastructure='way["waterway"]'"? 

I am trying to plot water body (e.g., lakes and reservoirs) on top of water line (i.e. rivers).

Comment: The different OSM tags are described in the wiki, see for example [natural=water](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Tag:natural%3Dwater).

Answer (score -1):

I have no experience with OSMnx but I guess you can download one of the usual [OSM extracts](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Planet.osm#Country_and_area_extracts) and filter it. For example by using [osmium-tool](https://osmcode.org/osmium-tool/) and extracting [elements](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Elements) [tagged](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Elements) with [natural=water](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Tag:natural%3Dwater) or [waterway=*](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Key:waterway). Then import it into OSMnx.

Comment: I want to work within Python framework, so I will try https://github.com/osmcode/pyosmium to use osmium-tool.